# ::before icons on mobile devices don't display

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

i've found this bug. I'm using Font Awesome 5 Free SVG with JS version 5.11.2, included in my web server. I've an ul with the marker that are font-awesome included in a background image. On desktop works well, but on mobile devices (testing on Android) the font awesome icons don't display. Here the code and the CSS:

```
<ul class="footer-info-contact">
    <li id="telefonox">xxxxxx</li>
    <li id="mailx">xxxxx</li>
</ul>



.footer-info-contact {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-info-contact li {
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 32px;
}

.footer-info-contact li::before {
    content: "";
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-left: -32px;
    width: 31px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color:  #FFF;
    background-image: url('/img/chicco-bianco.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#telefonox::before {
    content: "\f095";
}

#mailx::before {
    content: "\f0e0";
}
```

The first screenshot is the desktop version of the website and the icons display well:

[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wQfm.png)

On mobile devices, the icons dont't display:

[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSb1v.png)

How can i resolve this bug?

**Version and implementation**

```
Version: Font Awesome Free 5.11.2 SVG with JS
```

**Browser and version**

```
Firefox 70.0.1 (64 bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362 build 18362 x64
Firefox 68.2.0 on Android 7.0 on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge.
```

PS: sorry for bad english, i'm not good to write and speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This is the solution.

```
<ul class="footer-info-contact">
    <li><em class="fas fa-phone"></em>xxxxxx</li>
    <li><em class="fas fa-envelope"></em>xxxxx</li>
</ul>



.footer-info-contact {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-info-contact li {
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 32px;
}

.footer-info-contact li::before {
    content: "";
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-left: -32px;
    width: 31px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 45px;
    color:  #FFF;
    background-image: url('/img/chicco-bianco.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.footer-info-contact li svg {
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using all.css or use link https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.1.1/css/all.css it should fix your icon loading issue.
for mobile view image is attached below
[image]

```css
.footer-info-contact {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-info-contact li {
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 32px;
}

.footer-info-contact li::before {
    content: "";
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-left: -32px;
    width: 31px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: solid;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color:  #FFF;
    /* background-image: url('img/bg.png'); */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

li#telefonox::before {
   content: "\f095";
}

li#mailx::before {
    content: "\f0e0";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.1.1/css/all.css">
</head>
<body style="background: #ddd;">
<ul class="footer-info-contact">
    <li id="telefonox">xxxxxx</li>
    <li id="mailx">xxxxx</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same result as the second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reference to the actual font in your CSS. if you are referencing the font in your own CSS then you should have a reference like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('../font/font-name.eot?4247060');
    src: url('../font/font-name.eot?4247060#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../font/font-name.woff2?4247060') format('woff2'),
        url('../font/font-name.woff?4247060') format('woff'),
        url('../font/font-name.ttf?4247060') format('truetype'),
        url('../font/font-name.svg?4247060#font-name') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

you will also need to make sure you have the actual font files in the reference folder, in my case it is /font. Font Awesome uses /webfonts.

Comment: It's included in my project.